# What is "auto help" for keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts

With keyboard shortcuts enabled under my profile, pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (<kbd>?</kbd>) shows a help pop-up:

[image: help pop-up]

I'm wondering what exactly "auto help" (at the bottom) is, along with the "*auto-selects if nothing is selected" hint.

Comment: I'm such a heavy user of the keyboard shortcuts that I had forgotten half of what I just described in my answer below. Thanks for the opportunity to refresh my memory! This feature is fantastically well developed (it was originally an add-on, [developed by Balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one), and I've been using this for about 8 years now), it just becomes second nature and is almost invisible, as all good keyboard-driven interfaces should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several keyboard shortcuts comprise of a *combination* of keys, like voting (<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>U</kbd> to vote up, or <kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to vote down). If *auto help* is enabled, then when you hit the first key of such a combo, you are shown just-in-time help to tell you what options you have available from that point. This applies to any of the options with a `...` after them.

*Auto-selection* refers to picking either the question section, or any of the answers on the page; you'll note that it's actions that apply to a specific post, such as voting, that are marked there. When I press <kbd>V</kbd>, the nearest post I can vote on is 'selected' (its background gains a gradient on the left-hand side).

E.g. after pressing <kbd>V</kbd>, I see (hand-circled in red for obvious reasons):

> [image: Screenshot of small box with *vote...* keyboard shortcut options, <code>U</code> and <code>D</code> for up and down, respectively. A hand-drawn red circle inexpertly draws attention to it]

Note the gradient next to the box, that's indicating that my vote would apply to the question on this page. The *auto-selects* sentence is also no longer shown in the help box the moment the question or an answer is selected.

If I press <kbd>G</kbd> instead, I am shown the larger *go to...* menu instead:

> [image: larger *go to...* context help box with 11 site navigation options, again with red hand-draw circle]

In this case your question is still selected, but if I were to reload the page the gradient would not appear automatically, because <kbd>G</kbd> doesn't auto-select. However, in that case, the post-specific options like *post owner's profile* and *post revisions* are not available. You can manually select posts with the <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> keys.